# How to display angular properties like $pristine on a dynamic form

Tags: angularjs

I have this dynamic form, or at least part is dynamic.
I want to log out the values for some of the form properties on screen to help me out.
The following kind of works but the text on the page isn't updated when things change.

Any help greatly appreciated.

```
<div layout="column">
    <span>{{property.name}}-Error:{{roomForm['property'+property.id].$error}}</span>
    <span>{{property.name}}-Dirty:{{roomForm['property'+property.id].$dirty}}</span>
    <span>{{property.name}}-Touched:{{roomForm['property'+property.id].$touched}}</span>
    <span>{{property.name}}-Pristine:{{roomForm['property'+property.id].$pristine}}</span>
    <span>{{property.name}}-Valid:{{roomForm['property'+property.id].$valid}}</span>
</div>
```

Have also tried:

```
<span>{{property.name}}-Error:roomForm['property'+property.id].$error</span>
```

Which didn't work

---

Output from {{roomForm}}

```
{
    "$error" : {
        "required" : [{
                "$viewValue" : "",
                "$modelValue" : "",
                "$validators" : {},
                "$asyncValidators" : {},
                "$parsers" : [null],
                "$formatters" : [null, null],
                "$viewChangeListeners" : [],
                "$untouched" : true,
                "$touched" : false,
                "$pristine" : true,
                "$dirty" : false,
                "$valid" : false,
                "$invalid" : true,
                "$error" : {
                    "required" : true
                },
                "$name" : "Name",
                "$options" : null
            }, {
                "$viewValue" : "",
                "$modelValue" : "",
                "$validators" : {},
                "$asyncValidators" : {},
                "$parsers" : [null, null, null],
                "$formatters" : [null, null],
                "$viewChangeListeners" : [],
                "$untouched" : true,
                "$touched" : false,
                "$pristine" : true,
                "$dirty" : false,
                "$valid" : false,
                "$invalid" : true,
                "$error" : {
                    "required" : true
                },
                "$name" : "Capacity",
                "$options" : null
            }, {
                "$viewValue" : "",
                "$modelValue" : "",
                "$validators" : {},
                "$asyncValidators" : {},
                "$parsers" : [null, null, null],
                "$formatters" : [null, null],
                "$viewChangeListeners" : [],
                "$untouched" : true,
                "$touched" : false,
                "$pristine" : true,
                "$dirty" : false,
                "$valid" : false,
                "$invalid" : true,
                "$error" : {
                    "required" : true
                },
                "$name" : "property",
                "$options" : null
            }, {
                "$viewValue" : "",
                "$modelValue" : "",
                "$validators" : {},
                "$asyncValidators" : {},
                "$parsers" : [null, null, null],
                "$formatters" : [null, null],
                "$viewChangeListeners" : [],
                "$untouched" : true,
                "$touched" : false,
                "$pristine" : true,
                "$dirty" : false,
                "$valid" : false,
                "$invalid" : true,
                "$error" : {
                    "required" : true
                },
                "$name" : "property",
                "$options" : null
            }, {
                "$viewValue" : "",
                "$modelValue" : "",
                "$validators" : {},
                "$asyncValidators" : {},
                "$parsers" : [null],
                "$formatters" : [null, null],
                "$viewChangeListeners" : [],
                "$untouched" : true,
                "$touched" : false,
                "$pristine" : true,
                "$dirty" : false,
                "$valid" : false,
                "$invalid" : true,
                "$error" : {
                    "required" : true
                },
                "$name" : "property",
                "$options" : null
            }
        ]
    },
    "$name" : "roomForm",
    "$dirty" : true,
    "$pristine" : false,
    "$valid" : false,
    "$invalid" : true,
    "$submitted" : false,
    "Name" : {
        "$viewValue" : "",
        "$modelValue" : "",
        "$validators" : {},
        "$asyncValidators" : {},
        "$parsers" : [null],
        "$formatters" : [null, null],
        "$viewChangeListeners" : [],
        "$untouched" : true,
        "$touched" : false,
        "$pristine" : true,
        "$dirty" : false,
        "$valid" : false,
        "$invalid" : true,
        "$error" : {
            "required" : true
        },
        "$name" : "Name",
        "$options" : null
    },
    "description" : {
        "$viewValue" : "",
        "$modelValue" : "",
        "$validators" : {},
        "$asyncValidators" : {},
        "$parsers" : [null],
        "$formatters" : [null, null],
        "$viewChangeListeners" : [],
        "$untouched" : true,
        "$touched" : false,
        "$pristine" : true,
        "$dirty" : false,
        "$valid" : true,
        "$invalid" : false,
        "$error" : {},
        "$name" : "description",
        "$options" : null
    },
    "Capacity" : {
        "$viewValue" : "",
        "$modelValue" : "",
        "$validators" : {},
        "$asyncValidators" : {},
        "$parsers" : [null, null, null],
        "$formatters" : [null, null],
        "$viewChangeListeners" : [],
        "$untouched" : true,
        "$touched" : false,
        "$pristine" : true,
        "$dirty" : false,
        "$valid" : false,
        "$invalid" : true,
        "$error" : {
            "required" : true
        },
        "$name" : "Capacity",
        "$options" : null
    },
    "property" : {
        "$viewValue" : "",
        "$modelValue" : "",
        "$validators" : {},
        "$asyncValidators" : {},
        "$parsers" : [null],
        "$formatters" : [null, null],
        "$viewChangeListeners" : [],
        "$untouched" : true,
        "$touched" : false,
        "$pristine" : true,
        "$dirty" : false,
        "$valid" : false,
        "$invalid" : true,
        "$error" : {
            "required" : true
        },
        "$name" : "property",
        "$options" : null
    }
}
```

Comment: what did this display '{{roomForm}}' ? the key shoulds be the inputs names

Comment: a boat load of stuff.. but i dont see any of my dynamic fields.

Comment: It turned out it was just me.. there were no ID's in the data, so all the fields had the same name!

Answer (score 1):

Please try this: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xrdjpkzx/2/). You need to give the form fields a name to make Angular attach a property to the form (on the `$scope`).

The code is simple like:

```
<div ng-app="Joy">
  <form action="" name="myForm">
    <input type="text" ng-model="myInput" name="inputName">
    {{ myForm.inputName | json }}
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks. this has helped me understand whats possible regarding logging out the values.

Answer (score 0):

try this

https://jsfiddle.net/9y80vL6o/

```
<div ng-app="Joy">
  <form action="" name="roomForm">
    <input type="text" ng-model="myInput" name="Capacity" required>
    <pre>{{ roomForm['Capacity'] | json }} </pre>
  </form>
</div>
```

I don't know how you dynamicly create the output

Comment: thanks. this has helped me understand whats possible regarding logging out the values.